# how to create an array from compared array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

[image where data array comes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1sp3.png)

I'm still noobs at programming especially when using array T.T,
I want create new array after compared the data inside the array, 
the time object have 30 minute interval and if the interval become 1 hour it create new element inside array like the testDummy array sample.
for example, I have this kind of array bellow,

```
data = 
[
 {date: "2019-12-12", time: "10:00"},
 {date: "2019-12-12", time: "10:30"},
 {date: "2019-12-12", time: "11:00"},
 {date: "2019-12-12", time: "12:00"},
 {date: "2019-12-12", time: "12:30"},
 {date: "2019-12-12", time: "13:00"},
 {date: "2019-12-12", time: "13:30"},
]
```

and want to change it to this bellow :

```
testDummy = [
      {
        date :"2019-12-12",
        start_times :"10:00",
        end_times :"11:00"
      },
      {
        date :"2019-12-12",
        start_times :"12:00",
        end_times :"13:30"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: your goal it's not clear to me, can you add the code you tried so far?

Comment: It's not clear why you're skipping certain objects

Comment: Why is there no `start_time: "11:00", end_time: "12:00"` block (one hour difference just like `10:00 - 11:00`)? And why is there a `start_time: "12:00", end_time: "13:30"` (> 1 hour) block?

Comment: There are no clear guidelines on how the end object should be constructed.

Comment: Why is is 12-13:30 instead of 12-13?

Comment: @symlink I add image where i get the data array, everytime i click red circle the date and time get inside the data array, sorry for my bad english ;(

Comment: @ビートフリークス I think people are confused about which times to combine. For example, `data[0].time` and `data[2].time`, why skip `data[1].time`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, using a `reduce()` function should do the trick:

```js
data = 
[
 {date: "2019-12-12", time: "10:00"},
 {date: "2019-12-12", time: "10:30"},
 {date: "2019-12-12", time: "11:00"},
 {date: "2019-12-12", time: "12:00"},
 {date: "2019-12-12", time: "12:30"},
 {date: "2019-12-12", time: "13:00"},
 {date: "2019-12-12", time: "13:30"},
];

const res = data.reduce((acc,cur,idx,src) => {
   
   //skip objects where the time is the same as the new array's last endTime 
   if(idx > 0 && parseInt(acc[acc.length - 1].endTime) === parseInt(cur.time)){
      return acc;
   }
   
   //skip objects half hour times (e.g. "10:30")
   if(parseInt(cur.time.split(":")[1]) > 0){
      return acc;
   }
   
   cur["startTime"] = cur.time;
   
   //set the endTime to the latest time that is at least an hour past the cur startTime
   for(i = src.length - 1; i > -1; i--){
      if(parseInt(src[i].time) - parseInt(cur.time) < 2){
        cur["endTime"] = src[i].time;
        break;
      }
   }
   delete cur.time;
   
   acc.push(cur);
   
   return acc;
},[]);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: thanks so much, from your code I can solve my problem. XD n thanks for the advice